# Exporting a variable with dot (.) in it

Tags: shell, environment-variables, ksh

How to export a variable which has dot in it. I get 'invalid variable name' when I tried :

```
 export my.home=/tmp/someDir
-ksh: my.home=/tmp/someDir: invalid variable name
```

Even escaping metacharacter dot (.) din't helped either

```
$ export my\.home=/tmp/someDir
export: my.home=/tmp/someDir: is not an identifier
```

Comment: duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-include-character

Comment: unfortunately it din't listed when I typed/searched similar question. sorry. ..

Answer (score 83, accepted):

At least for `bash` the man page defines the export syntax as:

```
export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
```

It also defines a "name" as:

```
   name   A  word  consisting  only  of alphanumeric characters and under‐
          scores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an  under‐
          score.  Also referred to as an identifier.
```

Hence you really cannot define a variable like `my.home` as it is no valid identifier.

I am very sure your ksh has a very similar definition of an identifier and therefore does not allow this kind of variables, too. (Have a look at its man page.)

I am also very sure there is some kind of general standard (POSIX?) specifying, what is allowed as an identifier (and therefore a variable name).

---

If you really need this kind of variable for some reason you can use something like

```
env "my.home=/tmp/someDir" bash
```

to define it anyway. But then again, you will not be able to access it using normal shell syntax. In this case you probably need another language like perl:

```
perl -e 'print $ENV{"my.home"}'
```

For example

```
env "my.home=/tmp/someDir" perl -le 'print $ENV{"my.home"}'
```

should print your path.

Comment: It is because of in integration of ant . And unfortunately it does not allow to set/export variable from unix. Accepting your answer. ..

Comment: ant is usually configured by a single environment variable called `ANT_OPTS` or by ~/.antrc. No need for strange environment variable names for ant itself.

Answer (score 12):

While environment variables can have any name (including the empty string) not containing an equal sign or a null byte, shells map environment variables to shell variables and in most shells, variable names are limited to ASCII alphanumerical characters and `_` where the first character can't be a digit (except for the positional parameters and other special ones like `$*`, `$-`, `$@`, …, (which are not mapped to the corresponding environment variables)). Also note that some variables are *reserved/special* by/to the shell.

Exceptions to that:

- The `rc` shell and its derivatives like `es` and `akanga` support any name except the empty string, and those that are all-numeric or contain `=` characters (and always export all their variables to the environment, and beware of special variables like `*`, `status`, `pid`...):

  ```
  ; '%$£"' = test
  ; echo $'%$£"'
  test
  ; '' = x
  zero-length variable name
  ;
  ```

  However, it uses its own encoding for variables whose name don't contain alnums or for arrays when passed in the environment of commands being executed:

  ```
  $ rc -c '+ = zzz; __ = zzz; a = (zzz xxx); env' | sed -n /zzz/l
  __2b=zzz$
  __5f_=zzz$
  a=zzz\001xxx$
  $ env +=x rc -c "echo $'+'"
  x
  $ env __2b=x rc -c "echo $'+'"
  x
  ```
- AT&T `ksh`, `yash` and `zsh` (also `bash` but only for single-byte characters) support alnums in the current locale, not only ASCII ones.

  ```
  $ Stéphane=1
  $ echo "$Stéphane"
  1
  ```

  In those shells, you could change the locale to consider most characters as alpha, but still that wouldn't work for ASCII characters like `.`. You can fool `zsh` or `ksh` into thinking `£` is a letter, but not that `.` or any other ASCII character (where allowing characters in variable names is concerned, not for the `[[:alpha:]]` glob for instance).
- `ksh93` has special variables whose name contains a dot like `${.sh.version}`, but those are not mapped to environment variables and are special. The `.` is to make sure it doesn't conflict with other variables. If it had chosen to call it `$sh_version`, then it could have potentially broken scripts that used that variable already (see for instance how `zsh` has issues with its `$path` or `$commands` special array/hash variables (a la csh) that break some scripts).

Note that in addition to shells not supporting those variables, some shells like pdksh/mksh do **remove** them from the environment they receive (`bash` removes the one with an empty name, `ash`, `ksh` and `bash` remove those environment strings that don't contain a `=` character):

```
$ env %%%=test 1=%%% a.b=%%% mksh -c env | grep %%%
$ env %%%=test 1=%%% a.b=%%% bash -c env | grep %%%
%%%=test
a.b=%%%
1=%%%

$ perl -le '$ENV{""}="%%%"; exec "bash", "-c", "env"' | grep %%%
$ perl -le '$ENV{""}="%%%"; exec "zsh", "-c", "env"' | grep %%%
=%%%

$ echo 'main(){char*a[]={"sh","-c","env",0};char*e[]={"%%%",0};
    execve("/bin/ash",a,e);}'|tcc -run - | grep %%%
$ echo 'main(){char*a[]={"sh","-c","env",0};char*e[]={"%%%",0};
    execve("/bin/zsh",a,e);}'|tcc -run - | grep %%%
%%%
```

To sum up, best is to stick with variable names supported by most shells and even try to use upper case for environment variables (and lower case or mixed case for not-exported shell variables) avoiding those that are special in shells (like `IFS`, `PS1`, `BASH_VERSION`...).

If you do need to set such a variable in a shell that doesn't support them, but doesn't discard them, you can either reexecute yourself, with something like:

```
#! /bin/ksh -
perl -e 'exit 1 unless defined($ENV{"a.b"})' || exec env a.b=%%% "$0" "$@"
```

(obviously, if you need to do it in the middle of the script, that won't help, but you could then have a look at [that approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86785/22565) to save and restore the shell execution environment over a re-exec).
Or try the debugger approach:

```
gdb --batch-silent -ex 'call putenv("a.b=%%%")' --pid="$$"
```

(that one seems to work with `zsh`, `yash`, `csh` and `tcsh` on Linux amd64, but not with any of the other shells I tried (`mksh`, `ksh93`, `bash`, `dash`)).

Comment: `mksh` (and `pdksh`) indeed construct the environment processes they spawn get completely from scratch, using only those parameters exported in the current shell execution environment, so there is no way to pass those variables through those shells. (Note that the variables that _are_ passed are subject to change; e.g. I’m planning to support array exports for `mksh` some day.)

Answer (score 2):

As the other posts point out, the most common shells do not allow for setting environment variables with periods in the name.  However, I have found situations, particularly involving Docker and invoked programs, where the software required key values with periods.

However, in each of these situations, those key-value pairs could be passed to the program through other means than just environment variables.  For example, in Ant, you can use the "-propertyfile (filename)" to pass in a property file formatted collection of key-values.  Confd allows for "-backend file -file (yaml file)".

I passed the environment variables in the form "C__any_value='my.property.key=the value'".  I then switched the program invocation to first generate the file:

```
set | awk -- 'BEGIN { FS="'\''" } /^C__/ {print $2}' > my-key-values.txt
```

The `set` command, in Borne Shell, will output each property on a separate line in the form

```
C__any_value='my.property.key=the value'
```

The `awk` command will process only the environment variables starting with `C__`, then extract the values contained in the single quotes.

This method requires the environment variable value to be set in the precise form that the processing program requires.  Additionally, if your property value or key will contain single quotes, then you will need to change the awk field separator character to something you know that won't appear, and surround the value with that character.  For example, to use `%` as the separator:

```
$ C__1="%my.key=the'value%"
$ set | awk -- 'BEGIN { FS="%" } /^C__/ {print $2}'
my.key=the'"'"'value
```

(the precise output will depend on your shell.)  You will need to take extra steps to decode the quote escaping.

Comment: Particularly Elasticsearch on K8s seems to thrive on a.b style env vars by default; e.g. https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/720268f405865cf2974305878a021f4bed27c526/elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml#L153-L178

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @michas is quite correct, but it's possible to extend it to simulate `export` function with dot environment names.

To "export" such variable, you can `exec` current shell with `env` command. E.g. to export `test.env=foo` variable, use:

```bash
exec env "test.env=foo" $SHELL
```

Exec will replace current shell with a new process, where the new process will be a new instance of current shell (`$SHELL`) with additional environment variable `test.env` (added by `env "test.env=foo"`). So after this command you can access it from your process, e.g.:

```bash
perl -e 'print $ENV{"test.env"}'
```

Comment: I fail to see how this improves on that other answer as both seem to say the same thing (the only difference is that you use `exec` to _replace_ the current shell rather than to start a new shell session as a child process). Also note that `$SHELL` generally is the _login_ shell of the current user, which may differ from the current shell.