# Bash Script - Setting Local Environment Variables (Proxy)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, environment-variables, proxy

I am trying to create **2** scripts. One for setting local enviroment variables, and the other for unsetting local enviroment varibales.

Firstly, both scripts were created under the following commands:

`touch set-proxy.sh`
`touch unset-proxy.sh`

Then I made both of them executable:

`chmod 700 set-proxy.sh`
`chmod 700 unset-proxy.sh`

Then I went into the `set-proxy.sh` file and put the following inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

`export HTTP_PROXY=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
`export HTTPS_PROXY=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
`export HTTP-PROXY=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
`export HTTPS-PROXY=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
`export http_proxy=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
`export https_proxy=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
`export http-proxy=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
`export https-proxy=http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****`
```

Then I went inside the `unset-proxy.sh` file and put the following inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

`unset HTTP_PROXY`
`unset HTTPS_PROXY`
`unset HTTP-PROXY`
`unset HTTPS-PROXY`
`unset http_proxy`
`unset https_proxy`
`unset http-proxy`
`unset https-proxy`
```

I pretty much need a quick way to unset and set all proxy configuration. I thought creating two scripts would be the simplest way.

However, when I run `./unset-proxy.sh` or `./set-proxy.sh` I get the following error messages:

```
./unset-proxy: line 5: unset: `HTTP-PROXY': not a valid identifier
./unset-proxy: line 6: unset: `HTTPS-PROXY': not a valid identifier
./unset-proxy: line 9: unset: `http-proxy': not a valid identifier
./unset-proxy: line 10: unset: `https-proxy': not a valid identifier
```

(Then I get the same with the `set-proxy.sh` as well).

If someone could help point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong and how I can correct it, would be super appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are all those backticks for?

Comment: I thought backticks were used in shell commands to tell the script to run an exxecutable. Even when i remove the, still doesn't work and still get the same error. Thanks for the question though.

Comment: Still get the error

./unset-proxy: line 5: unset: `HTTP-PROXY': not a valid identifier
./unset-proxy: line 6: unset: `HTTPS-PROXY': not a valid identifier
./unset-proxy: line 9: unset: `http-proxy': not a valid identifier
./unset-proxy: line 10: unset: `https-proxy': not a valid identifier

Comment: Why are you using `./script` (which creates its own process, which then goes away) versus `. ./script` (which runs the code within the context of the current process)

Comment: ah not too sure really. So when i try running ` . ./unset-proxy` i get the same error but in a different format: `-bash: unset: `HTTP-PROXY': not a valid identifier`

Comment: All those have hyphens in their name. Are you sure a shell variable can contain a hyphen?

Comment: I'm not too sure, would have thought they could contain `-`, there must be a way to put `-` in a shell script, well i would have thought anyways.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there are several mistakes here. First, your variable assignment expressions shouldn't be inside backticks. The backticks are a (somewhat dated) syntax for [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). I think what you were going for was [single-quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html). [Quoting variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) is done to preserve string literals and prevent [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Also, you can't use the hyphen character in your variable names. Here is an excerpt from the [Bash Manual, Chapter 2: Definitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions):

> **name**
>
> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an **identifier**.

Also see the following posts for more information:

- [Can shell variable include - character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-include-character)
- [Allowed characters in linux environment variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names)

Here is what your scripts might look like after removing the backticks and the hyphens:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set_proxy.sh

export HTTP_PROXY='http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****'
export HTTPS_PROXY='http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****'
export http_proxy='http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****'
export https_proxy='http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****'
```

and:

```
#!/bin/bash
# unset_proxy.sh

unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

One final note: executing a script causes it to run in a subshell, so the environment variables won't affect your active shell session. See, for example, the following post:

- [Set a parent shell's variable from a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541321/set-a-parent-shells-variable-from-a-subshell)

The short answer is that you can't. So if you want your scripts to modify your current shell environment then you have to "source" them, e.g.:

```
source set_proxy.sh

source unset_proxy.sh
```

Comment: The last part of your comment was definitely the most helpful for me. Understanding that you cannot set variables for your terminal shell from inside a subshell saved me a lot of googling. Thanks!

Comment: If your user/pwd and proxy address are the same to all proxies type, you can use this:
export {all,tcp,http,https,socks,ALL,TCP,HTTP,HTTPS,SOCKS}_proxy='http://nick:nick@proxy.***.***.com:****'